# How to make horizontal dropdown content area stick around?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal menu with dropdown content boxes.   I'm using the same method I'd use for a vertical menu with children that expand on :hover of their parent.  It works fine, except that I can't seem to find a method that forces the dropdown content to stick around once the cursor moves from the parent element itself.  You can see what I mean at http://asubtleweb.com/clients/kingswood/ ... The dropdown content isn't clickable because it contracts as soon as the mouse moves from its parent element.

Here's my CSS:

```
#header_menu nav { display: table; width: 30%; float: left; text-align: center; }
#header_menu nav ul, nav#mainmenu ul { list-style-type: none; }
#header_menu nav li { display: inline; margin-right: 2.5%; }
#header_menu nav a, nav#mainmenu a { font: 400 1.25em 'Oswald', sans-serif; color: black; text-transform: uppercase; }
#header_menu li .navhover { display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; background-color: black; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); color: white; text-align: left; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden; transition: all 1s linear; -wekbkit-transition: all 1s linear; }
#header_menu li:hover .navhover { max-height: 300px; min-height: 300px; }
#header_menu li .navhover article { margin: 20px; }
#header_menu li .navhover.news article { width: 30%; margin: 2.5% 0% 2.5% 2.5%; float: left; }
```

...and my HTML:

```
<div id="header_menu">
<nav>
<ul>

    <li id="mission">
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/mission">Mission</a>
      <div class="navhover">
        [[CONTENT]]
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="news">
      <a href="#">News</a>
      <div class="navhover news">
          [[CONTENT]]
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="reserve"><a href="#">Reserve</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

I've also tried making each parent element its own absolutely positioned block that expands on :hover, with no luck.  I didn't expect to have so much trouble with the concept, but it's stumping me.

Comment: the problem does exist in your actual site however the code you posted seems to work [check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bFru4/1/), and of course it should work. So there should be something wrong in your actual site.

Comment: If you ask a question, have the courtesy to at least check back and if possible accept an answer that worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

As [Francesco Frapporti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23792952/3163075) pointed out:

Simply add `z-index: 1;` to `#header_menu li .navhover`

Edit: There is an error on your website `moveWindow is not defined` see `body` element

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `z-index: 1;` to `#header_menu li .navhover`

Comment: Yes, it is as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your css....

```
#header_menu li .navhover:hover{min-height:0;max-height:0;}
```

then it should work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent element you are using with `:hover` doesn't actually "touch" the child element. So there is space between the parent and child element and that causes the parent element to lose focus when moving the mouse toward the child.

Choose whichever method you like to eliminate the gap between parent and child. Make the parent  larger, move the child closer to the parent, etc.